# Superfish dropdown position

Tags: jquery, navigation, drop-down-menu, superfish, suckerfish

Does anyone know if it is possible to have different positions for the dropdown UL's for superfish? I have a horizontal navigation bar, on the left side I would like the dropdowns to align to the left of the button, on the right side I would like them to align to the right of the button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you add a class to the items on the left side and right side such as .leftItem or .rightItem then target the dropdown and position it with css?

Such as:

.leftItem .dropdownClass {left:0px;}

.rightItem .dropdownClass {right:0px;}

Comment: Thanks, it's been some time since I've asked this question. But your answer is on point, that's how I've been doing it since 2009 ;)